# error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.lib

Tags: visual-studio-2010, boost

I made a simple console application which need Boost libraries,
but when I try to compile, I get:

```
fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.lib'
```

[image]

However, I included `c:\boost 1_55_0\libs` in my library directories, as well as in the additional library directories in the linker settings.

I entered `libboost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.lib` in additional dependencies, but still get the error.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you haven't got a typo in the directory-name or the lib-name? Are you compiling and linking with the same configuration in which you added the lib? (here "Debug") I just checked on my system with that boost lib, and it works.

Comment: @mr_georg ya i tried many times.i posted the images here so far which i did.but till now the problem is not solved.will u pls help me

Comment: Have you checked that the file is effectively in that directory (maybe it is in ..\stage\lib)? Have you built boost yourself or got a compiled version?

Comment: @mr_georg there is no path like \stage\lib.i build with bootstrap.bat.All lib files are in both libs folder as well as bin.v2 folder.I linked both but still getting this error.

Comment: Do you see this particular file (`libboost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.lib`) in `c:\boost 1_55_0\libs`? Compare every symbol.

Answer (score 0):

you have to make sure that 'libboost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.lib' file is found in 'c:\boost 1_55_0\libs' folder. If not, try to install the boost library again following the steps in this link: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/bbv2/installation.html

Comment: It's better to include the most important parts of the linked page in your answer, to avoid that your answer becomes invalid if the linked page changes.